# Azure Function FunctionTimeout is being ignored

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm running a function app with several c# functions (v2) in Azure (.net core 3.5.).
In the host.json file I added functionTimeout parameter to prolong the default timeout but it is not working. Functions are still timing out much sooner.

Going through similar posts I found that many people had to tweak something in startup.cs. but I don't have it (I used the standard azure function template in visual studio). Do I need it so host.json would not get ignored? Or is there an issue with the host file?

Any help appreciated.

This the host.json file I cain see in the app service editor:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:09:00"
}
```

[host.json printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JqHt.png)

Comment: check if you deploy it right. Could you confirm how you are deploying your function app? It is likely that you are running it from a ZIP file or the next deployment is overwriting your changes.

Comment: Yes it's a zip deploy

Answer (score 0):

Check your appfiles so you confirm that you deployed it right
[image: check]

Comment: Hi, yes in App files I can see the host.json as well and with a correct value.

Comment: try to decrease it because i think its maximum 10 minutes for less than premium subscription

Comment: but I have it set to 9 minutes so it should be fine

Comment: dear @ddeiml just try less than 9

Comment: I tried 7 minutes but still failing after 3 minutes

Comment: does it fail because timeout or something else?

Comment: It's timeout.  It seems that it is a 230 seconds timeout for an Azure Load Balancer which affects http trigger functions. There seems to be no easy way around it, I will need to use durable orchestration function. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Goodluck with your work